# React Native and FastAPI issue

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-native, fastapi

I'm running into an issue while creating a React Native application. I'm using FastAPI as by back-end. While making this call to my backend, nothing happens.

```
  function sendAkt() {
    fetch("https://192.168.1.5:8000/newActivity", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: ime,
        desc: opis,
        place: mjesto,
        team: tim,
        typeOf: pickerSel,
        id: users.id,
      }),
    })
    .then(_=> console.log('rea for the minute'))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

No error, the console of the backend doesn't ever report that a call to the backend route was ever made. It seems that the fetch just hangs. Since around 3 minutes later this pops up in the console

```
Network request failed
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:505:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This is the backend route I'm calling

```
@app.post('/newActivity')
async def unos(request: NewActivity):
    print('route Reaches')
    # name = request.name
    # desc = request.desc
    # place = request.place
    # team = request.team
    # typeOf = request.typeOf
    # id = request.id
    # year = 10

    # new_activity = Activities(activity_type_id=typeOf, academic_year_id=year,
    #                           description=desc,
    #                           user_id=id, team_id=team, title=name, location=place)

    # session.add(new_activity)
    # session.commit()

    return JSONResponse(content='Uspijeh')
```

and this is the CORS setup in my backend

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['http://localhost:19001'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

I've been at this for hours and I don't have any idea what it might be causing the issue

Comment: Are you 100% sure your server is reachable at `192.168.1.5:8000`?

Comment: Do you use Uvicorn or some other server? How do you start your server?

Comment: Yeah since I'm reaching the server on the different routes with the same applications. I'm using Uvicorn (starting with command Uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0)

Comment: Are you using docker or some container?

Comment: Nope running it locally

Comment: Does https://192.168.1.5:8000/docs open in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really dumb issue. I was calling a local server with `https` instead of `http. Changing to` http` fixed it